# Vertical Collapsible Tree in RShiny using collapsibleTree

Tags: shiny, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to build an Rshiny app which requires a tree like structure to be displayed. For this, I am using package called `collapsibleTree` in R. Tree displayed using this package is in horizontal direction, But, I am just curious, if there is a way to display it in vertical direction? I went through their documentation but couldn't find any.
Below, is the reproducible code. Also, I am using `bsModal` for the tree to be displayed on a popup window, the alternate way I am thinking of changing the orientation of popup (From horizontal to vertical, not really sure, if the same can be achieved).

```
library(shiny)
library(collapsibleTree)
# Define UI for application that draws a collapsible tree
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Collapsible Tree Example 2: Shiny Interaction"),
    # Show a tree diagram with the selected root node
    mainPanel(
      collapsibleTreeOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
# Define server logic required to draw a collapsible tree diagram
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderCollapsibleTree({
       hierarchy <- c("wool","tension","breaks")
    collapsibleTree(
      warpbreaks, hierarchy
    )
  })
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You could use the package `d3Tree`. It has an option to display collapsible tree vertically.

Comment: There is also `echarts` which has vertical and also radial, the R package is `echarts4r`.